# Container for sap.m.GenericTile

Tags: sapui5

For sap.m.StandardTile, we had the brilliant sap.m.TileContainer, but I am not able to find anything similar for the sap.m.GenericTile.

Basically I'm looking for a control that contains multiple Generic Tiles and will resize & center them automatically, depending on the device.

Right now, this is what I am doing:

```
<GenericTile header="{/0/header}" subheader="{/0/subheader}" press="onTilePress">
<TileContent>
<ImageContent src="{/0/src}"/>
</TileContent>
</GenericTile>

<GenericTile header="{/1/header}" subheader="{/1/subheader}" press="onTilePress">
<TileContent>
<ImageContent src="{/1/src}"/>
 </TileContent>
</GenericTile>
```

Isn't there an automated way of doing this besides having to call every entry in my JSON file manually?

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried putting them in a flexbox container or gridlayout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Flexbox` to aggregate and bind items rather than individually/manually binding them and `grid layout` to control the view for devices. The `defaultSpan` control property in **GridLayout** determines how the tiles will look depending on the device screen size i.e. XL, L, M & S screen displays.

**[See working example](https://embed.plnkr.co/DuDdUe/)**

```js
//Example data.json

{
  "ProductCollection": [{
    "productHeader": "Tile Header - 1",
    "productSubHeader": "Tile SubHeader - 1",
    "ProductPicUrl": "sap-icon://competitor"
  }, {
    "productHeader": "Tile Header - 2",
    "productSubHeader": "Tile SubHeader - 2",
    "ProductPicUrl": "sap-icon://badge"
  }, {
    "productHeader": "Tile Header - 3",
    "productSubHeader": "Tile SubHeader - 3",
    "ProductPicUrl": "sap-icon://broken-link"
  }, {
    "productHeader": "Tile Header - 4",
    "productSubHeader": "Tile SubHeader - 4",
    "ProductPicUrl": "sap-icon://create"
  }, {
    "productHeader": "Tile Header - 5",
    "productSubHeader": "Tile SubHeader - 5",
    "ProductPicUrl": "sap-icon://pending"
  }, {
    "productHeader": "Tile Header - 6",
    "productSubHeader": "Tile SubHeader - 6",
    "ProductPicUrl": "sap-icon://decision"
  }, {
    "productHeader": "Tile Header - 7",
    "productSubHeader": "Tile SubHeader - 7",
    "ProductPicUrl": "sap-icon://process"
  }, {
    "productHeader": "Tile Header - 8",
    "productSubHeader": "Tile SubHeader - 8",
    "ProductPicUrl": "sap-icon://accept"
  }, {
    "productHeader": "Tile Header - 9",
    "productSubHeader": "Tile SubHeader - 9",
    "ProductPicUrl": "sap-icon://alert"
  }]
}
```

```html
<!--In **Main.view.xml** -->

<Page id="page" title="Page Title" showHeader="true" enableScrolling="true">
  <content>
    <Panel height="100%" width="100%" backgroundDesign="Transparent">
      <layout:Grid containerQuery="true" defaultSpan="XL12 L12 M12 S12" width="100%">
        <layout:VerticalLayout width="100%" class="gridWrapper">
          <FlexBox alignItems="Center" alignContent="Center" direction="Row" renderType="Bare" wrap="Wrap" width="100%" displayInline="true" fitContainer="true" items="{/ProductCollection}">
            <items>
              <GenericTile header="Headers" subheader="Subheader" press="onTilePress">
                <TileContent>
                  <ImageContent src="{ProductPicUrl}" />
                </TileContent>
              </GenericTile>
            </items>
          </FlexBox>
        </layout:VerticalLayout>
      </layout:Grid>
    </Panel>
  </content>
</Page>
```